# Doctrine 2 configuration with MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine

I'm busy with Doctrine2, but I can't get it to work.

Everything works fine out of the box with sqlite. But when I try to change the database in the sandbox demo to MySQL I'm getting confused. This is what I did. I created a database, changed the connectionOptions array to:

```
$connectionOptions = array(
    'driver' => 'pdo_mysql',
    'path' => __DIR__.'/mysql.php'
);
```

the 'path' entry exists and looks like this:

```
$connectionParams = array(
    'dbname' => 'db_test',
    'user' => 'test',
    'password' => 'p4ssw0rd',
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'driver' => 'pdo_mysql',
);
```

When I run the command to create the database:

```
 php doctrine orm:schema-tool:create
```

Which gives me the error:

```
 no database selected
```

Seems to be a clear message. But how can I change the databasename, cause the one specified in mysql.php (see above) does excist and should be the one it uses! I searched for it for hours, but I cannot find it anywhere.

Comment: Can you show us some more of the code, kind of hard to diagnose with just two lines. Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Is this the Doctrine 2 sandbox? This worked for me:

```
// sandbox/bootstrap.php

$connectionOptions = array(
    'driver'   => 'pdo_mysql',
    'host'     => '127.0.0.1',
    'dbname'   => 'your_database_name',
    'user'     => 'username',
    'password' => 'password'
);

$em = EntityManager::create($connectionOptions, $config);
```

Comment: In this answer 'path' should be changed to 'host' to work with the latest versions of doctrine.

Comment: Updated. Thanks. I think Doctrine was still beta when this question was originally raised.

Answer (score -1):

The Cookbook code is also available for download. See [here](http://phphints.wordpress.com/2010/11/11/doctrine-2-orm-cookbook-example/) for the details. Look at **cli-config.php** after you download it.

Comment: This link is now behind a private blog.

Comment: @Kevin Sedgley Yes, I haven't tinkered with Doctrine for a long time, and that entry is from 2010. So by now, the information in the link may be obsolete. You might check https://github.com/kkruecke/doctrine-2-cookbook